# Laravel 5.2 + MongoDB + Auth = User must implement CanResetPassword interface

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I installed the authentication on Laravel 5.2, jenssegers/laravel-mongodb with make:auth.

Registration, login works fine. 
The only functionality who causes error is the reset password :

```
UnexpectedValueException in PasswordBroker.php line 238: User must implement CanResetPassword interface.

in PasswordBroker.php line 238 at PasswordBroker->getUser(array('email' => 'xxx@xxx.xxx')) in PasswordBroker.php line 82 
at PasswordBroker->sendResetLink(array('email' => 'xxx@xxx.xxx'), object(Closure)) in ResetsPasswords.php line 67 
at PasswordController->sendResetLinkEmail(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PasswordController), 'sendResetLinkEmail'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 78 
at Controller->callAction('sendResetLinkEmail', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146 
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(PasswordController), object(Route), 'sendResetLinkEmail') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94 
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24 
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103 
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96 
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(PasswordController), object(Route), object(Request), 'sendResetLinkEmail') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54 
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController', 'sendResetLinkEmail') in Route.php line 174 at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140 
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724 at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64 at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49 
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62 at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37 
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59 at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103 
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726 
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699 at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675 
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246 
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44 
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32 
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) 
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103 
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132 
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99 
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Here is user.php model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class User extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
use AuthenticableTrait;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
?>
```

Here is app.php :

```
(...) Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class, 
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class, 
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class, ], (...)
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you implemented the CanResetPasswordContract interface ?

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, 
                                    CanResetPasswordContract {
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    ...
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords